# Onward travel details for Schengen visa through Austria

Tags: visas, austria

I'm applying to the Austrian embassy for a multiple-entry Schengen visa. As per the checklist, they require "proof of onward travel in EU". Had a couple of questions regarding this:

1. Is this a mandatory requirement since pre-booking rail/bus bookings for travel out of Austria and then not obtaining a visa, would be wastage of money?
2. Is there a way to reserve rail/bus tickets in a manner similar to reserving flight and hotel tickets before applying for a visa?

Thanks in advance!